# Why does the constructor handle the exception but I get a "not handled exception error" when I use it

Tags: java, exception, hashmap

I have two constructors :

```
protected WordStore() {
    this.bigMap = new HashMap<>();
}

protected WordStore(String file) throws IOException {
    this.bigMap = new HashMap<>();
    String line = "";
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));)
    {
        while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.print(line);
            }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The file could not have been loaded correctly");
        }
    }
```

The second one handles the `IOexception` and it compiles correctly but when I try to initialise a new map from `WordStore`:

```
WordStore store1 = new WordStore("text.txt");
```

I get a compiling error saying that the `IOException` has not been handled. Obviously the constructors are in a different class than the store initialisation. 
This should be fairly easy to answer I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`throws` and `catch` are different.
When a method declares in its signature that it `throws` an exception, the caller has to handle it by either rethrowing it back or by catching it.

```
protected WordStore(String file) throws IOException {
 //doing something that can throw an IOException
}

//Caller handles it
try {
    new WordStore("text.txt");
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    //Handle the exception
}

//Or the caller (Assuming the caller is the main method) can throw it back
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new WordStore("text.txt");
}
```

Here, since you are already catching the `IOException`, you can remove the `throws` clause from the constructor.

Comment: Mark the answer as solution.

Comment: @Nomade as soon as I will able to confirm it I will.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the Throw statement

Comment: Your answer is a good, but try to explain more as @user7 did.